# Customizing how Chakra components use the color scheme

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Chakra allows you to define and pass color schemes to components, but as far as I've been able to tell, it doesn't allow you to customize how those color schemes are used. For example, the button component will use the 500 shade of whichever color scheme you pass in as its default background and a darker shade for the hover background. Suppose I wanted to invert these though, I'm hoping to do something like...

```
Button: {
  baseStyle: {
    bg: colorScheme.700,
        _hover: {
          bg: colorScheme.500,
        },
    },
}
```

Is there any way to define how color schemes are used for a given component? It seems like to override the default shading choices, you have to override all colors explicitly, but hopefully I'm missing something.

Comment: Still, an actual question is expected.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The question is: is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can explore Chakra's source to see how they do this for their components. They're not coded any differently than how you can define your own styles.

We know Buttons utilize the colorScheme prop, so I looked in the code to find out how they apply the prop.

Their core component styles are defined in a base theme and [Buttons are no different](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/c77973070dac3468d701ccb2e7b8ff87c8d430f4/packages/components/theme/src/components/button.ts#L26-L52C3). The source shows various examples of variants being used, but here's the `ghost` variant definition:

```js
const variantGhost = defineStyle((props) => {
  const { colorScheme: c, theme } = props


  if (c === "gray") {
    return {
      color: mode(`inherit`, `whiteAlpha.900`)(props),
      _hover: {
        bg: mode(`gray.100`, `whiteAlpha.200`)(props),
      },
      _active: { bg: mode(`gray.200`, `whiteAlpha.300`)(props) },
    }
  }


  const darkHoverBg = transparentize(`${c}.200`, 0.12)(theme)
  const darkActiveBg = transparentize(`${c}.200`, 0.24)(theme)


  return {
    color: mode(`${c}.600`, `${c}.200`)(props),
    bg: "transparent",
    _hover: {
      bg: mode(`${c}.50`, darkHoverBg)(props),
    },
    _active: {
      bg: mode(`${c}.100`, darkActiveBg)(props),
    },
  }
})
```

As you can see, there's something special about this definition (in addition to some helper functions being utilized).

In all of Chakra's examples, they use static objects to override styles. But that's not a necessity. You can use this `defineStyle` function to return a dynamic object based not only on the current colorMode, but the colorScheme passed to the component! `defineStyle` can be used on your `baseStyle` property, as well as your `variants` and `sizes` properties too.

You can access `defineStyle` by importing it from `@chakra-ui/react` like this:

```js
import { defineStyle } from '@chakra-ui/react'


const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Button: defineStyleConfig({
      baseStyle: defineStyle(props => {
        return {
          color: `${props.colorScheme}.500` 
        }
      }),
    }),
  },
})
```

It's not necessary, but you can get fancier, like in the Chakra source, and use the `mode` helper function to select different colors for your light and dark mode.

Comment: After I wrote this, I found this example: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#customizing-global-styles

You can see they use a plain function there and apply the type to it for TypeScript. `defineStyle` appears to be a pretty wrapper for it, but you can probably use a plain function too.